# How to get forum title in url in phpbb?

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I am trying to have forum title in the url so for eg, my forum title "grass is green" shows ups in the url as www.myforum/forum/grass-is-green.php and not www.myforum/forum/viewforum.php?f=5

I have tried doing the changes given here http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=1053375 but the changes are not reflected and the url stills appears as before

Please help me out .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The mod you linked to doesn't affect the URL, it looks up the title and changes a link's text in a post. What you are looking for is a SEO mod that rewrites / redirects URLs. A quick look through the phpBB site and I see a couple, but they seem to have issues. These types of mods can also break if a topic gets renamed. The original "...&t=250" link would work, but the ".../old_topic_name/" would break.

To quote one of the phpBB Support team members: "We do not recommend any SEO mods. There is no real reason to mess with the URLs like that. The search engines index them fine as-is."

Hope that helps!